# How can I enable users to create dashboards without edit access to the report in Power BI?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dashboard

I share a workspace with a number of users in Power BI service. I have a report and a dashboard within this workspace, but I would like to allow users to create their own dashboards without giving the edit access to the report.

Is there any workaround for this which would enable my users to create dashboards off my report without them having to download and republish the report and also without them having access to the report?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing nice, sadly.

The new Home feature shows 6 tiles from 2 of your "most important" dashboards.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-power-bi-home-and-global-search/

"Key metrics at a glace" section

But you dont have any control over exactly what is shown, and you cant create your own tiles.

Another hack is to go to a report page and use the File menu to get an Embed code. Copy the HTML fragment (iframe) , then add it to any Dashboard as a Web Content tile.